# Access perl attribute in associative array

Tags: arrays, perl

Is there an easier way to access the value of the 'type' attribute without looping through the whole object to find it?

```
[
  { type => "voipPassword", vals => ["data"] },
  { type => "sn", vals => ["data"] },
  { type => "voipExtension", vals => [data] },
  { type => "cn", vals => ["data"] },
  { type => "telephoneNumber", vals => [data] },
  { type => "objectClass", vals => ["data"] },
  { type => "phoneMAC", vals => ["data"] },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access `type` directly like this example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;    

my $ref = [
            { type => "voipPassword", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "sn", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "voipExtension", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "cn", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "telephoneNumber", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "objectClass", vals => ["data"] },
            { type => "phoneMAC", vals => ["data"] },
          ];

print $ref->[0]->{'type'} . "\n";
print $ref->[1]{'type'} . "\n";
```

Output:

```
voipPassword
sn
```

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks for this, im looping through a load of these and some of these dont have all 7 types so im getting: `Use of uninitialized value in string eq at /SCRIPT line 27, <DATA> line 522.`, which isn't error-ing the script but means i cant use the results well, is there a way to suppress these? I've used an eval but it's not suppressing the message

Comment: That's because `eval` avoids exceptions (i.e. `die`), not warnings. Try something like `my $type = $ref->[0]{type} // "default";` which provides a default for `$type` if `$ref->[0]{type}` is not defined. Alternatively, just switch off warnings you're finding unhelpful... `no warnings qw(uninitialized);`.